# Javascript: Best way to find a date (dd/mm/yyyy) in a string

Tags: javascript, validation, date

OK I mentioned here `dd/mm/yyyy` but it could be `mm/dd/yyyy`. What I really mean to say here is that I need a way to identify if the following pattern exists in a string in javascript.

```
\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}
```

The above is what I would use in .NET. I'm trying to create a JS function to return a boolean indicating if a date is in the string or not.

```
function containsDate(inputString){
  //Some magic in here..
}

//Expected results
containsDate("Today is 05/07/2013") = true
containsDate("Today is Friday") = false
```

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at javascript [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). You will need method [`.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
function containsDate(inputString){
  return /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/.test(inputString)
}
```

**Update:** 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hYYF/) from @tessi to see it in action.

Answer (score -1):

```
function containsDate(inputString){
  regex = new RegExp(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/)
  return regex.test(inputString)
}
```

Comment: Please don't.  There is no reason to combine the RegExp constructor with a regular expression literal.  Either use, `var regex = new RegExp("\\d{2}\/\\d{2}\/\\d{4}")` or (preferably) `var regex = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/`.  And don't forget the `var` either.  This introduces an unnecessary global variable.